# Which FLOSS text editor is most like kwrite without being KDE-based?

Tags: linux, text-editors

Among text editors on Linux, I usually prefer KWrite.  I like that I can quickly turn on/off line numbers and line wrap in the View menu.  Other settings are easy to change.  Other text editors I've used in the past, such as Gnome's gedit, bury line numbering and wrapping checkboxes deeper into the menu system, making it more distracting to change while concentrating on real work.

However, KWrite is a KDE app. On Ubuntu it drags in over a dozen other packages, which I suspect I don't really need.  Why would a text editor need all that?  It's slower to start up than some other editors I've tried.  I'm also trying to run an all-gnome system w/o any KDE, just to see how far I get with it.

So, what GUI text editor isn't KDE-based, has few dependencies and quick start-up, easy to change line wrap and numbering,  and general similarity to KWrite?   What comes closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ScITE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) is closer to Kate than KWrite in functionality, but is GTK/Gnome based and has the line numbering, wrapping, and many other options available right in the menus, just like KWrite.

It's included in the Ubuntu repositories.  Just install the `scite` package.